# Grails: Integrating the Underlying Java(Spring+Hibernate) web app

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, gsp, pojo

I have currently developed an application using (hibernate/spring MVC) now I want to use grails controllers and views for the application how do I fix this top layer on top of the base application.

1. I have already put the hibernate cfg & hbm's in the `grails-app/conf/hibernate` directory so all that works. I want to integrate the service layer also. The Controller and View is the only part I need to do in grails. How?

Comment: If you want controllers and view in Grails, what part is Spring MVC playing?

Comment: @cdeszaq Actually i have aleady designed the application . now i need to remove that springs mvc thing and put the grails lid.!

Comment: What are you looking to gain by switching to Grails? Some idea behind the motivation may help in suggesting a solution.

Comment: @cdeszaq  Well i dont know it s a module that i m supposed to be doing soon on a Organization's project so here i am kind of developing a prototype.But basically the Validation part for the forms and the entire application flow using controllers.

Comment: Perhaps the possiblity that taking Spring MVC out of the way.

Comment: Converting from an existing project to Grails is much harder than a greenfield Grails project, but the brute-force way is to simply re-write the controllers and views in Grails. I'm sure there are more elegant ways available, however.

Comment: @cdeszaq Thanks..True any tutorials or sites you could suggest! Also what about the second question ? Why is my form showing a drop down for a sub-object in the domain class ?

Comment: Are you using scaffolding to create the form?

Comment: @cdeszaq :yes def scaffold = <class name> ; i am still a beginner. but i would be glad if you could introduce me to a better way.! Sorry !

Comment: @RajeevNadgauda - Please post that 2nd question as it's own Stack Overflow question. Combining multiple questions into one is frowned upon within the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: @cdeszaq : Very Sorry About that! Have removed it.Posted a new one.!